# How to give users a permissions to read an object on Parse.com table?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to give only a couple of users to read an object in my Parse.com table.

It goes like this:

User enters information and a name of user that will be able to read this information 

The information has been sent to servers

Only the user that has permission to read can read this information.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse does not offer that on a column level, you can only set an ACL on a per-object or per-class level. You can read more about Data & Security in the documentation [1] of Parse

[1] https://parse.com/docs/data#data_security

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I meant an object, my English isn't so good... Anyway, thanks

Comment: I've checked the link, and I don't understand it. Can you give an example?

Comment: I need to give to a user acl for it. how to?